# Compile error of Swigibpy Python package

Tags: python, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm trying to install Swigibpy package for Python. I'm on Windows 7 64bit, Anaconda 32bit (Python 2.7.9).

https://github.com/Komnomnomnom/swigibpy

I tried to follow the instruction in this thread
[Making Cython work with Python 3.4 on Anacondas, Windows 7 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322699/making-cython-work-with-python-3-4-on-anacondas-windows-7-64-bit)

To install Visual Studio for Python 2.7..

I get this error. Anyone know how to solve it?

```
C:\swigibpy-master>python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc
running build_ext
building '_swigibpy' extension
C:\Users\tmgike\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.
0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DIB_USE_STD_STRING=1 -IIB
-IIB/src -IIB/shared -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\PC /TpIB/src/EClientSoc
ketBase.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\IB/src/EClientSocketBase.obj /D_CRT_
SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /EHsc /wd4355 /wd4800
EClientSocketBase.cpp
IB/shared\EClientSocketBaseImpl.h(308) : error C3861: 'snprintf': identifier not
 found
error: command 'C:\\Users\\tmgike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\
Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

C:\swigibpy-master>
```